# Правильный парсинг JSON

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, afnetworking

Привет!
Никак не получается нормально отпарсить JSON.
Метод API возвращает данные(через AFNetworking) примерно с такой структурой:

```
    {
        response =     {
            items =         (
                            {
                    avatar = "http://xxx.ru/avatar/medium/1394065865874.jpg";
                    balance = 848;
                    banner =                 {
                        items =                     (
                                                    {
                                name = Main;
                                url = "http://ya.ru";
                            }
                        );
                    };
           );
    };
}
```

Чтобы получить значение переменной "balance" я делаю примерно следующее:

```
NSDictionary *response = [responseObject objectForKey:@"response"];
NSArray *items = [response objectForKey:@"items"];
NSString *balance = [[items objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"balance"];
```

Здесь все нормально и значение получить удается. Сложности начинаются, при получении данных в объекте "banner". Например, для получения значения "url":

```
NSDictionary *banner = [items valueForKey:@"banner"]; 
NSDictionary *bannerItems = [banner valueForKey:@"items"];
NSString *url = [bannerItems valueForKey:@"url"];
// можно и через objectForKey, результат тот же
```

И при выводе переменной url получаем его со скобками:

```
(
        (
        "http://ya.ru"
    )
)
```

Как правильно получить вложенные значения? Пробовал и через NSArray - тоже не получается.

**UPD:**

Проблема решилась:

```
NSDictionary *banner = [[items firstObject] objectForKey:@"banner"];
NSArray *bannerItems = [banner valueForKey:@"items"];
NSString *url = [[bannerItems firstObject] valueForKey:@"url"];
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что проблема вызвана невнимательным разбором.

Answer (score 1):

То что вы написали в качетве примера ни разу не json, к тому же не знаю чем конкретно вы прасите json, но есть подозрение (по названиям) что bannerItems это не словарь, а массив и вместо:

```
NSDictionary *bannerItems = [banner valueForKey:@"items"];
NSString *url = [bannerItems valueForKey:@"url"];
```

должно быть

```
NSArray *bannerItems = [banner valueForKey:@"items"];
NSString *url = [[bannerItems firstObject] valueForKey:@"url"];
```

Comment: в таком виде выдает AFNetworking, Сервер отдает JSON.
Заменил NSDictionary на NSArray. В результате значение все равно со скобками. Крашится при получении длины url. [__NSArrayI length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17e92ec0

Comment: Так из этого следует что url у вас не строка, а массив, причем похоже что в массиве тоже массив (двойные скобки). Я не работал с AFNetworking, но похоже он имеет какие-то надстройки над массивом, позволяющие выдирать поля json из всех элементов массива и возращать тоже в качестве массива. А вторую строку тоже заменили?

Comment: Проблема решена, посмотри апдейт вопроса:)